# NSKeyedArchiver will not archive simple dictionary with enum as value

Tags: swift, nskeyedarchiver

I am trying to use `NSKeyedArchiver` to "archive" a simple dictionary. The key is of type `String` and the value is an `enum`.

The following example illustrates what I am trying to do:

```
import Foundation

enum Friend: String, Codable {
    case Ben, Max
}

let friends: [String: Any] = [ "bestFriend" : Friend.Ben ]
let archivedFriends = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: friends)
```

This code can be copied into a playground and the result will be the following error:

> error: Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT.

Sadly, I was not able to copy the stack trace so I had to create a screenshot:

[image: Stack Trace]

To test that the `enum` is indeed the problem I changed the code to the following:

```
import Foundation

let friends: [String: Any] = [ "bestFriend" : "Ben" ]
let archivedFriends = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: friends)
```

This works so the question is:

**What am I missing in my first code example to get `NSKeyedArchiver` to work with the given dictionary?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the raw value instead of using the enum directly.

```
let friends: [String: Any] = [ "bestFriend" : Friend.Ben.rawValue]
let archivedFriends = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: friends)
```

Comment: That does work. Thank you very much. But it seems a bit odd to be honest. Especially, because it makes the `Codable` protocol obsolete and I thought the whole point of adding the protocol to an `enum` was to make the whole process a bit more "user friendly". The `rawValue` is just the string representation of the enum.

Comment: @Jens Encoding with `NSKeyedArchiver` requires things to be `NSCoding`, not `Codable` (unless you explicitly call `encodeEncodable`). An `enum` can’t conform to `NSCoding`, but it’s `String` `rawValue` bridges to `NSString`, which does.

Comment: @ItaiFerber Since Swift 4 `Codable` should work for enums as well. I saw multiple blog posts like this: https://littlebitesofcocoa.com/318-codable-enums. As long as I use an `enum` with a type that itself implements the `Codable` protocol it should work. Or did I read that wrong?

Comment: @Jens Yes, that is the way to make `enum`s `Codable`. However, `NSKeyedArchiver` does not work in terms of `Codable`, but in terms of [`NSCoding`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscoding), which is a different API altogether. Things which are `Codable` are not `NSCoding` and vice versa. `NSKeyedArchiver` has API in Swift for encoding `Codable` things (`encodeEncodable` and `decodeDecodable`) but that does not apply to `enum` values inside of `[String : Any]`; it must be called explicitly.

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing that up @ItaiFerber!